# dropdownClassName datepicker to disable animation or transition

Tags: javascript, typescript, antd

is there a way to disable dialog animation of RangePicker or DatePicker in antd?

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-datepicker-forked-129d43?file=/src/App.js:581-615

```
<RangePicker open={open} />
```

I would like the dialog to open instantly

I tried to add

```
<RangePicker open={open} dropdownClassName="something" />
```

and apply `transition: none;` and `animation: 0;` it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

just apply this

```
.ant-calendar-picker-container {
       animation:none !important;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/antd-datepicker-forked-n6vtsv